# Change the voice to female in dialogflow cx

Tags: google-api-python-client, dialogflow-cx

How can the voice be changed to female using APIs (python client library) in Dialogflow CX? We tried the steps mentioned in this document but nothing worked.(https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/patch)

Answer (score 0):

Now You can select Multiple voice in Dialogflow CX
[VoiceBot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWOQ.png)

Here is full docs :- https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/wavenet

Answer (score -1):

For [Dialogflow CX Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/python), you can change the voice to female through the [detectIntent](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.DetectIntentRequest) request and specifying the [outputAudioConfig](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.OutputAudioConfig).[synthesizeSpeechConfig](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.SynthesizeSpeechConfig).[voice](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.VoiceSelectionParams).[ssmlGender](https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow-cx/latest/dialogflowcx_v3/types.html#google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3.types.SsmlVoiceGender).

Also note that Dialogflow CX currently does not support voice configurations for [Speech and IVR](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-speech) in the Dialogflow CX console.